# Formwizard with custom queryset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I have a problem with formwizard. In step 3 of the wizard I use a filtered query which depends on choices from step 1 and 2. My wizard works fine when moving forward, but when a user presses previous, or changes the choices of step 1 and 2, things go wrong (validation error or filters won't work).

Here is my forms.py:

```
class BoekForm3(forms.Form):
    Activiteit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Activiteit.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
```

If I use queryset Activiteit.objects.none() in forms.py the correct fields in step3 of the wizard show up right, but the step3 always give a validation error.

If I use queryset Activiteit.object.all() in forms.py the correct (filtered) fields show up in step3 when going forward, and the form validates. However when a user presses previous in step4 the filter is gone, and all choices are available.

**Edit2:** ok I found out that get_form is read every time (removed my previous edit about this). The problem with my code is that when a user goes back from step4 to step3, the step get_form is using, is step4. I tried to change:

"if step == 'step3'"

into:

"if step == 'step3' or step == 'step4':"

in my view, but this results in a key error on Activiteit

I think that the fields are updated moving to step3, but the form isn't. I have included my views.py below.

```
class BoekingWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        plaatjes = Activiteitsgroepen.objects.all()
        context = super(BoekingWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == 'step1':
            context.update({'plaatjes': plaatjes})
        return context

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(BoekingWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        if step == 'step3':
            x = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('step1') or {}
            filter1 = x['Type_activiteit'].Groep
            y = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('step2') or {}
            if y['Aantal_personen'] < 76:
                filter2 = 'kleinere groepen'
            elif y['Aantal_personen'] > 76:
                filter2 = 'grotere groepen'
            else:
                filter2 = 'geen selectie'
            reeks = ['1','2','3']
            if y['Dagdeel'] in reeks:
                filter3 = 'Dagdeel'
            elif y['Dagdeel'] == '4':
                filter3 = 'Hele dag'
            elif y['Dagdeel'] == '5':
                filter3 = 'Middag + Avond'
            elif y['Dagdeel'] == '6':
                filter3 = 'Dag + Avond'
            form.fields['Activiteit'].queryset = Activiteit.objects.filter(Soort__Groep = filter1).filter(Grootte__Naam = filter2).filter(Dag__Omschrijving = filter3)
        return form
```

Comment: you should try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Shouldn't `if step == 'step3':` actually `if step == '3':` as per docs?

Comment: @Rohan good point. I use custom templates for every step, then the step number changes into the names I used when defining the Templates.

Comment: @masterofdestiny The query is not the problem, the problem is the information passed between the steps of the wizard, used for filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more and more that Formwizard doesn't support what I want. I therefore started to work with normal forms, and store the cleaned_data in a session. The advantage is that I have more control, and I know better what is going on. Here the the idea:

```
def BoekingForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('BoekForm2'):
            form1 = BoekForm1(request.POST)
            if form1.is_valid():
                request.session['Data_BoekForm1'] = form1.cleaned_data
                if 'Data_BoekForm2' in request.session:
                    x = request.session['Data_BoekForm2']
                else:
                    x = None
                form2 = BoekForm2(initial = x)
                return render_to_response('boeking/form2', {
                    'form2': form2,
                }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

        else:
                return render_to_response('boeking/form1', {
                    'form1': form1,
                }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        if request.POST.get('BoekForm3'):
            form2 = BoekForm2(request.POST)
```

Unless somebody comes with a solution the solve my question within Formwizard, I will have to mark my own answer as the solution.

Comment: can u plz tell me what u r doing to go from 1 from to another?means on a button click of form u r calling the same view?

Comment: In the template I have a confirm button: <input type="submit" name="BoekForm2" value="Volgende" id="BoekForm2"/> then this information is in the request.POST: if request.POST.get('BoekForm2'):

You can also include a field in the form like this:
<input type="hidden" name="BoekForm2" value="Volgende"/>

Comment: i am having problem in passing values..can u plz point out my mistake..if i show u my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522419/passing-values-between-views-django...plz see the catherine ans..i am using that views now..

Comment: no it is not solved..it is still not getting the value..it always go to else

Comment: It always go's here('/accounts/login/')..even though i select post_type=job

Comment: If you look at my code, I have multiple forms in one view. Between the forms I store the cleaned data in a session. I will comment further on your topic.

Comment: but i want to call the other form on button click.can u plz guide me how can i do this using one view?

Comment: The code in my answer above does exactly what you want. Please take your time now, and decide to use formwizard, or the code above. If you decide to use my code, try to understand how it works exactly, and modify it for your needs. Also read the Django documentation about sessions. I will be happy to help you when you run into specific problems.

Answer (score 3):

To use custom steps names, you must initialize the wizard class with a list of tuples of step name and form class

```
FORMS = [("step1", myapp.forms.Step1Form),
         ("step2", myapp.forms.Step2Form)]
```

and in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^wizard/$', BoekingWizard.as_view(FORMS)),
)
```

Comment: I know, but that is not the problem, since the wizard is working when I step forward.